# When does the Taylor coefficient of $e^{\sin x}$ vanish?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, generating-functions

If $f(x)=\frac{a_1}{1!}x+\frac{a_2}{2!}x^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}x^3+\frac{a_4}{4!}x^4+\cdots$ is an exponential generating function for $\{a_k\}_{k\geq1}$ then
$$e^{f(x)}=1+\frac{a_1}{1!}x+\frac{a_1^2+a_2}{2!}x^2+\frac{a_1^3+3a_1a_2+a_3}{3!}x^3+\cdots$$
is related to the number of set partitions. A particular case $f(x)=e^x-1$ results in the Bell numbers via $e^{e^x-1}$.

Consider now the choice of $f(x)=\sin x$. I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that $b_n=0$ iff $n=3$ when $e^{\sin x}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{b_n}{n!}x^n$?

Comment: This sequence is https://oeis.org/A002017. Perhaps this would help someone to answer

Comment: $b_m=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{m}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^k \sigma_m(m-2k)$, where $\sigma_m(n)$ is number of ways to put $m$ distinct objects in $n$ identical groups each having odd number of elements.